# Windows 10. Python. VLC in fullscreen mode does not play in foreground

Tags: python, windows, fullscreen, vlc

I have a python daemon process which periodically starts VLC player in fullscreen mode, plays some video and stops it:

```
import vlc
...
player = vlc.MediaPlayer()
player.set_fullscreen(True)
...
player.play()
...
player.stop()
...
```

But if I open or focus any other window after I start my script, VLC player pops up in fullscreen mode but don't go over this new top-level window.
There is no such problem for Linux Mint. VLC in fullscreen overwrite anything, no matter what.

Is there any solution or workaround for such problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by using ***--video-on-top*** flag with ***vlc.Instance***:

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self._instance = vlc.Instance(['--video-on-top'])
        self._player = self._instance.media_player_new()
        self._player.set_fullscreen(True)

    def play(self, path):
        media = self._instance.media_new(path)
        self._player.set_media(media)
        self._player.play()

    def stop(self):
        self._player.stop()
```